# Scripts as web apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I successfully deployed a Script as a webapp:

https://docs.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxJvSRpH7dMmrmMnkJW6LRZwMImqQ_5MT8tWMYUVXryWlgw1Fck/exec

And looking in the docs, tutorials and here, I did not found how to import it.
How can I import this script in a spreadsheet in another Google Account?

And I also published to Public Gallery two days ago, but unfortunately without answer until now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you read the [docs on Libraries ?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries?hl=fr-FR#includeLibrary)

What is not very clear to me is why you are talking about webapp and script attached to spreadsheet ? these are supposed to be 2 different utilisation of script... which one do you actually mean ?

Or did I misunderstood your question ?

Comment: I was thinking that publishing as a webapp would be an Script that anyone could import inside a spreadsheet. But looks that it is not the case. 

I readed the Librarie docs, but this is not what I want to do. I would like to allow users to install my script in their Spreadsheet.
Look like I have to wait the approval to be in Public Gallery.